# How to find Max element in SQLite?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I need select the maximum ID of PolygonId column. I save my data like this

```
        string sql = "create table Polygons (PolygonId int, PointId int, X double, Y double)";

           // Выполнение нашей команды
           using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection))
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                int pointId = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < listOfCustomPolygons.Count; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < listOfCustomPolygons[i].listOfVertexes.Count; j++)
                    {
                        string strSQL =
                            string.Format("INSERT INTO Polygons (PolygonId,PointId,X,Y) Values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}')",
                                            i+1,pointId,listOfCustomPolygons[i].listOfVertexes[j].X,
                                          listOfCustomPolygons[i].listOfVertexes[j].Y );
                        pointId++;

                        using (SQLiteCommand insertCommand = new SQLiteCommand(strSQL, m_dbConnection))
                        {
                            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
```

After this I want select the max value from table Polygons and column PolygonId, but I got an IndexOutOfRangeException. How a can solve this problem?

```
   using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + openFileDialog.FileName + ";Version=3;"))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    string selectMaxId = "Select Max(PolygonId) From Polygons";

                    string selectQuery = "Select * From Polygons";

                    SQLiteCommand selectMaxCmd = new SQLiteCommand(selectMaxId,connection);
                    SQLiteDataReader dataReader = selectMaxCmd.ExecuteReader();
                    int maxId = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Select Max(PolygonId) From Polygons"]); // This is don't work! Why?
```

Comment: Use parameters with your query, but the real problem is the way you are reading from the reader, You should read some article about basic ADO.Net

Answer (score 2):

I found out the solution! It should look like

```
string selectMaxId = "Select Max(PolygonId) From Polygons";
SQLiteCommand selectMaxCmd = new SQLiteCommand(selectMaxId,connection);
object val = selectMaxCmd.ExecuteScalar();
int maxId = int.Parse(val.ToString());
```

I hope it can help somebody who face with similar problem)

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't create table every time you run your code :) But you probably know that

You type like this:

`int maxId = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Select Max(PolygonId) From Polygons"]);`

Try this:

```
string selectMaxId = "Select Max(PolygonId) From Polygons";
SQLiteCommand selectMaxCmd = new SQLiteCommand(selectMaxId,connection);
SQLiteDataReader dataReader = selectMaxCmd.ExecuteReader();

int maxID = -1;

while(dataReader.read())
{
    maxID = (int)dataReader.GetValue(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work. I also got IndexOutRangeException! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
//This Works for me in WPF C#: 

int MaxNum=0;
sqliteCon.Open();
string Query = "SELECT MAX(Promo_No)FROM Promo_File";
SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqliteCon);
SQLiteDataReader DR = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (DR.Read())
{
   MaxNum = DR.GetInt16(0);
}
sqliteCon.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!
You have to learn the difference method of SQLiteCommand.
1.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader().  Get a SqlDataReader.
2.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteScalar().  Get a single value from the database.

Microsoft Doc:
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.region";
Int32 count = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();